# How to add existing S3 bucket (not AWS, but my custom provider) to Nexus Storage

Tags: nexus, sonatype

How could I add S3 solution for storage from other Cloud-Provider, not AWS ones. I have an other solution of S3 (my custom S3 service), but not AWS. Therefore I wanted to ask how could I add other storage to Nexus?

I have only public link for S3 and gave all rights for bucket, but it fails to add it to Nexus, due to

```
An error occurred saving data. Unable to initialize blob store bucket: test, Cause: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

I have tried to change location from default to eu2 (European Union (Germany) but I have this location on my solution for S3)

Comment: My personal experience with this on a Dell ECS infrastructure is that I lost a lot of time to get to something half functional with a final communication from sonatype support: "we only support amazon s3 for time being, not any other s3 implementation. We might consider looking at your problem without any warranty of success if you buy this very expensive license". Please note that this kind of question not directly related to programming is [off-topic](/help/ontopic) on SO. Try https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

I've used awscli for interacting with Dell ECS. In that scenario the main change required was to correctly specify the *ECS server IP* including port via the `--endpoint-url` parameter.

I suspect that if you provide the correct parameter under `Advanced Connection Settings > Endpoint URL`, then you will be able to successfully leverage a custom minio server, Dell ECS, etc.

Nexus Endpoint URL Configuration:

[image: Nexus Endpoint URL Configuration Screenshot]

[Access Dell ECS with AWSCLI](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000021492/ecs-how-to-access-buckets-when-using-the-aws-cli)